# Converting date using Angular JS filter fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-filter

I am using angular js filter to format a date on the controller. A user selects a date from a `uib-datepicker-popup`. It is this date that I want formatted using `ISO 8601` (yyyy-mm-dd) date format. I then log my the date picked by the user and get something like this

`Sat Aug 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EAT)`

However I then use angular $filter like this

`$filter('date')(new Date(vm.my_date), 'yyyy-mm-dd');`

and wind up with the date as

`2016-00-20`

Here is my the code on my controller

```
        // Logs Sat Aug 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EAT)
        console.log(vm.my_date);

        var converted = $filter('date')(new Date(vm.my_date), 'yyyy-mm-dd');

        // Logs 2016-00-20
        console.log(converted);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the `mm` in your filter the filter thinks that you mean `minutes` with that.
For the filter to understand the `m`s need to be UPPERCASE so it understands that you mean `month`.
Changing the filter from:

```
var converted = $filter('date')(new Date(vm.my_date), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

to

```
var converted = $filter('date')(new Date(vm.my_date), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

would fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea the fix was just that simple.

Answer (score 2):

filter should be like 'yyyy-MM-dd'
check this documentation [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the ui.bootstrap.dateparser? No need to create a custom filter when there's already one built into ui.bootstrap.datepicker. [Angular Directives for Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)